# Build website with both jquery and angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I read on the [FAQs of Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq) that "*Angular can use jQuery if it's present in your app when the application is being bootstrapped*".

My question is, is it a good practice or would there be any conflict or performance issue if a site contains jquery and angularjs scripts?

I plan to build a site that would contain both jquery and angularjs.

The reason for this is that I plan to use jquery mostly for plugins like carousel, slideshow, lightbox, calendar, form validation, etc. and angularjs will be mostly used for data binding. (mostly ajax request then bind it a table using ng-repeat, etc)

Do you think this is a good approach or should I just stick with only one (jquery or angular) to do all the process?

This is because I'm not sure how much plugins like carousel, slideshow, lightbox, etc. are available in angular and if I would be able to find such plugins that may be present in jquery but not in angular.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It can go along just fine, but I recommend users of angular to only use angular, because it takes a whole other approach you shouldn't mix the usage of them.

Answer (score 1):

**From a technical point of view** it is no problem to use AngularJS along with jQuery. In fact Angular itself contains a light version of jQuery: [jqLite](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element). So you never really use it completely without jQuery. For example basic selectors are always available. However, this is not sufficient for running your jQuery plugins.

**From an architectural point of view**, mixing jQuery and Angular can be confusing. Certain things can be done the "jQuery way" or the "Angular way" -- such as attaching a click handler to an element. If you include jQuery, you should be consistent with regard to these issues. I suggest you do it the Angular way (e.g. use `ng-click` in your templates instead of `$(selector).on('click',...)` in your directive's link function -- or even worse in services or elsewhere).

In your case it is justified to use both together. There are tons of great jQuery plugins and there isn't an Angular version for all of them yet. I would include jQuery only for those plugins and discipline myself not to use jQuery features apart from that.

Comment: _There are tons of great jQuery plugins and there isn't an Angular version for all of them yet._ And this is why jquery is still on my plate. I'm pretty new to Angular and saw that AngularJS 2 will be rolling out soon leaving AngularJS 1 floating. I think in time, when AngularJS should be well establish like Jquery, I would then consider using full Angular on future projects. But that time, another framework will be on the loose.. LoL

Answer (score 0):

So obviously, you'll get a hit from initial loading of your site, because not only will you be getting Angular scripts you'll also be calling for jQuery scripts.

There is no problem with you doing this, it is something you'll have to weigh up, pros and cons.

As for this:

> The reason for this is that I plan to use jquery mostly for plugins
>   like carousel, slideshow, lightbox, calendar, form validation, etc.
>   and angularjs will be mostly used for data binding. (mostly ajax
>   request then bind it a table using ng-repeat, etc)

So with a bit of searching (ui bootstrap) you'll find that stuff like **carousel, slideshow, lightbox, calendar** can all be done with Angular Directives (Angular's way of interacting with the DOM). I created a massive widget drag and drop screen all with Angular - no jQuery. So what you can achieve is limitless* and is a lot easier to do with straight Angular because you're less likely to run into digest cycle issues.

**Form validation** what an interesting point, I believe this to be a pain point for most web developers for years. What is nice about Angular is this comes supported straight out of the box. And it is good (and symmantic). Take email validation for example:

```
<input type="email" ng-model="person.email" ng-required />
```

Angular will automatically regex this email to check it is valid. And it will also make sure there is a value. The power doesn't stop there. Like I said it is extensively supported out of the box.

The advice I can give you is, search google for Angular components, test them out before making your decision. But I can assure you that, I have done everything you're talking about purely in Angular.

But the joy of programming that it is entirely up to you!

* you imaginations the limit, angular will find ways to limit you..... etc. etc.

Answer (score -1):

This is not [recommended](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together). BTW, jQlite is already included in Angular...

Comment: I don't read this article as discouraging the combination of jQuery and Angular in general. UI bootstrap just solves a certain problem and therefore it is preferred over using jQuery for a certain purpose.

Answer (score -1):

It is not a good practice to use `jquery` with an `angular js`.Angular consist of almost all the functionalities that you can get from jquery.

Although if you have some specific scenarios where you need the strongly type model binding of angular js and you want to use jquery for your other work then you can use both in a single project.